# Scrapy / Python: How can I add an item to a list created inside a class?

Tags: python, list, class, collections, scrapy

I am trying to add an object to a list created inside another object.
So, here are my classes:

```
# Clases auxiliares
class job(scrapy.Item): # containing class, it has a List of 'batches'
    job_name = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    start = scrapy.Field()
    end = scrapy.Field()
    operator = scrapy.Field()
    recipe = scrapy.Field()
    planned = scrapy.Field()
    executed = scrapy.Field()   
    def __init__(self):
        self.batches = [] 

class batch(scrapy.Item): # this class goes inside a job class, and
                          # also stores a list of 'units'
    batch_name = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    start = scrapy.Field()
    end = scrapy.Field()
    def __init__(self):
        self.units = [] 

class unit(scrapy.Item): # Finally, this class stores a list of data
    unit_name = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    start = scrapy.Field()
    end = scrapy.Field()
    operator = scrapy.Field()
    recipe = scrapy.Field()
    def __init__(self):
        self.datos = []
```

And here is the code I am trying to run (with errors, unfortunately):

```
def inicializa_batches(self, lista_batches, jobs):

# 1- the param lista_batches is an extract() of a portion of the 
# response.css with the required data

# 2 - The param jobs is a list of job() objects previously created
    for batchname in lista_batches:
        bn =  str(batchname.strip()) #mejor recibir pura cadena de texto
        if len(bn) > 0:
            newbatch = batch() #declare a new batch object
            newbatch['batch_name'] = bn
            for job in jobs:
                nom_job = job['job_name']
                if nom_job[0:4] == bn[0:4]: #4 letter match

                    job['batches'].append(newbatch) # <-- Error!!
        self.log(bn)
```

and the error I get is:

```
AttributeError: Use item['batches'] = [] to set field value
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation ([link](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#scrapy.item.Field)),

> The Field class is just an alias to the built-in dict class and doesn’t provide any extra functionality or attributes. In other words, Field objects are plain-old Python dicts. A separate class is used to support the item declaration syntax based on class attributes.

Therefore, you could just define `batches`, `units` and `datos` as a `Field` object as the following

```
# Clases auxiliares
class job(scrapy.Item): # containing class, it has a List of 'batches'
    job_name = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    start = scrapy.Field()
    end = scrapy.Field()
    operator = scrapy.Field()
    recipe = scrapy.Field()
    planned = scrapy.Field()
    executed = scrapy.Field()
    batches = scrapy.Field()   


class batch(scrapy.Item): # this class goes inside a job class, and
                          # also stores a list of 'units'
    batch_name = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    start = scrapy.Field()
    end = scrapy.Field()
    units = scrapy.Field()

class unit(scrapy.Item): # Finally, this class stores a list of data
    unit_name = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    start = scrapy.Field()
    end = scrapy.Field()
    operator = scrapy.Field()
    recipe = scrapy.Field()
    datos = scrapy.Field()
```

In the function, you could change it into the following

```
def inicializa_batches(self, lista_batches, jobs):

# 1- the param lista_batches is an extract() of a portion of the 
# response.css with the required data

# 2 - The param jobs is a list of job() objects previously created
    for batchname in lista_batches:
        bn =  str(batchname.strip()) #mejor recibir pura cadena de texto
        if len(bn) > 0:
            newbatch = batch() #declare a new batch object
            newbatch['batch_name'] = bn
            for job in jobs:
                job['batches'] = []
                nom_job = job['job_name']
                if nom_job[0:4] == bn[0:4]: #4 letter match

                    job['batches'].append(newbatch)
        self.log(bn)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But now everytime I run the code, the batches are overwritten (a job can have many batches, a batch can have many units, and a unit can have multiple different data).

It's because of job['batches'] = [] inside the "for job in jobs:" loop.

Comment: What is the expected behavior of the `inicializa_batch` function?

Comment: inicializa_batches is going to browse all the document for a specific text in a specific class, and it has to create a series of batch objects and append them to the batches field of the job object iterated in the "for job in jobs" loop.

Why am I doing this? because the structure of the source file is not properly formatted -- the whole document is a table, no divisions of any kind, no divs or anything.

Luckily the key data point have specific classes, however there's no way to differentiate to what job each batch belongs to.